# SQL Query to count multiple values from one table into specific view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I like to request your help. I can get the results seperated but now i want to create a query which has it perfect for a external person. my explanation:

I have a statistics database with in this database a table when some records comes in and each records has several columns with values etc...

Now one of these columns is called "MT" 
MT Column can have only one of the following values per records: A,B,C,D,E
The records also have a columne called TotalAmount which indicate a size of a value outside the database. This TotalAmount column is numeric without decimals and can have a value between 1 and 10.000.
And the last part is the records it self, the table has X amount of records.

So Basicly i need to create a query which seperates each MT value and calculates the amount of records per MT and the sum of TotalAmount.

This is on SQL Server 2005.

Many thanks for your assistance!

Comment: next time try to provide a 
  [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
   much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very hard to guess without a full db schema. But I think you need.

```
 SELECT MT, Count(*), SUM (TotalAmout)
 FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY MT
```

Comment: Hi Juan Carlos, 
I feel so dumb right now, I was thinking to difficult. 
This worked perfect! Many thanks!